# Python, How to record 24-bit audio with pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, 24-bit

I need to record 24-bit audio using python, and I try pyaudio to do that. However, it seems that pyaudio doesn't support 24-bit recording.

I set the format to 24-bit(pyaudio.paInt24), it record and save as a 24-bit file. However, it's not a true 24-bit recording. I plot the wave signal and found that it's just 16-bit precision but zero-padding to 24-bit.

Could anyone tell me how to record true 24-bit audio with python? Thanks

Comment: What device are you recording from? Does the device / device driver support 24 bit?

Answer (score 0):

PyAudio is able in record in 24-bit, all that you need to do is put an `pyaudio.paInt24` in your formant type.

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt24,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=44100,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=1024)
```