# How to get 24-bit samples from USB audio device using Python?

Tags: audio-recording, wave, python-sounddevice, 24-bit, pyaudioanalysis

I am trying to get a stream of 24-bit audio samples from some USB audio device using Python.
I already searched for some solutions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741655/python-how-to-record-24-bit-audio-with-pyaudio) thread that is using PyAudio stream with a format of pyaudio.paInt24, unfortunately I still got 16-bit samples. I tried to record with PyAudio stream and save with WAVE, sample code:

```
    def initialize(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.format,            # pyaudio.paInt24
                                  channels=self.channels,        # 1
                                  rate=self.fs,                  # 16000
                                  input=True,
                                  input_device_index=self.input_device_index,
                                  frames_per_buffer=self.chunk)  # 1024

    def run(self):

        frames = []

        for _ in range(0, int(self.fs / self.chunk * self.duration)):
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            frames.append(data)

        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()

        # write recording to a WAV file
        wf = wave.open(self.recorded_file, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()
```

I also tried the same the SoundDevice, sample code:

```
    def initialize(self):
        sd.default.samplerate = self.fs         # 16000
        sd.default.channels   = self.channels   # 1
        sd.default.device     = self.input_device_index

    def run(self):

        data = sd.rec(int(self.duration * self.fs), dtype=np.int32)
        sd.wait()

        # Save file
        wf = wave.open(self.recorded_file, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(3)
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(data))
```

In order to make sure that the problem occurs when receiving the samples and not while saving them, I made sure that a 24-bit audio file can indeed be saved with WAVE, using this sample code:

```
import wave
with wave.open(path_to_file_to_read, mode='rb') as rb:
    white_noise = rb.readframes(rb.getframerate())

    with wave.open(path_to_file_to_save+'_save_with_wave.wav', mode='wb') as wb:
        wb.setnchannels(rb.getnchannels())
        wb.setsampwidth(rb.getsampwidth())
        wb.setnframes(rb.getnframes())
        wb.setframerate(rb.getframerate())
        wb.writeframesraw(white_noise)
```

Also, I put a break point right after the recording was finished to take a look on the recorded samples and I see that it looks like 16-bit:
[image: PyAudio samples debugging]I will note that in order to make sure that the USB audio device does send me the 24-bit samples I did a recording using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and indeed I got 24-bit, for some reason I can not do anything similar with Python.

Is there a simple way to record 24-bit samples using Python code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **PyAudio** and **SoundDevice** use **portaudio** bindings between some windows sound architecture and python.
**PortAudio** does not suppport full depth 24 bit, and the result is 16 bit of audio with additional 8 zero bits.
**SoundCard** supports 24 bit - https://soundcard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In order to get real 24 bit samples, you can use the following:

```
import soundcard as sc
import soundfile as sf

FS = 16000
TIME_IN_SEC = 5
FRAMES = FS * TIME_IN_SEC
DEVICE_NAME = 'default'
FILE_PATH = 'abc.wav'    

# get device
audio_device = sc.get_microphone(DEVICE_NAME)

# receive samples
data = audio_device.record(samplerate=FS, numframes=FRAMES)
    
# write recording to a WAV file
sf.write(FILE_PATH, data, FS, subtype='PCM_24')
```